# how to get details of user in php

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal

I developed a PayPal integration page in PHP. Payment and success pages are also working but I am not getting user email.

home.php page

```
<?php
     ob_start();
      session_start();
      require_once 'dbconfig.php';
      error_reporting(0);
   // if session is not set this will redirect to login page
   if( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
         header("Location: index");
         exit;
          }
     $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
     $row=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select *from `at_reg_user` 
     where `email`='$user_id'"));
     $name=$row['fname'].' ' .$row['lname'];
       ?>
```

PayPal button in home.php page

```
       <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                                 <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YYHR897NQVQCY">
                                 <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                                 <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>
```

This is my page success page:

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';
ob_start();
session_start();
if( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
header("Location: index");
exit;
  } else {
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `at_reg_user` where `email`='$user_id"));
$email = $row['email'];
   }


 $txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
 $payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
 $currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
 $payment_status = $_GET['st'];

 if($_GET['st']=="Completed") {

$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
$payment_status = $_GET['st'];

//select statement for disabling user to perform back button

$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT txn_id FROM `payments` where `txn_id`='$txn_id'"));
if ($result > 0) {
    echo("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                      window.alert(' Sorry you have already done payment')
                      </SCRIPT>");
    } else {

     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `payments`(`txn_id`, `payment_gross`, `currency_code`, `payment_status`) VALUES ('$txn_id','$payment_gross','$currency_code','$payment_status')");

      if ($query) {
        echo $email;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $txn_id;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $payment_gross;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $currency_code;
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $payment_status;
        echo "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                      window.alert(' Payment Successful but not inserted')
                      </SCRIPT>");
    }
   }

 }


      echo "<h4>Payment done Successfully. Note down the above transaction details for further assistance </h4>";
      header("Refresh:10; url=home");
   ?>
```

When I try to print email with echo `$email`, it's not printing. I need to get emailid to insert that into the payments table.

Comment: ... you integrated paypal in a site full with security lacks?! Dude, I would really recommend you to remove this function... http://bobby-tables.com learn about SQL injections and how to prevent them. Actually, everybody can hack your whole site in a few seconds. Use prepared statements, NEVER NEVER NEVER put GET or POST vars directly in your query! Especially not if you handling paypal !!!! Sorry, but that drives me crazy... thats extremly dangerous what you're doing there!! You can get in big troubles because of such things...

Comment: @Twinfriends i think i have to learn PDO prepare statments with mysqli

Comment: You're mixing up things. Prepared statements is a way how you keep your querys safe. PDO and mysqli are two different drivers for querying the database. So either you learn Prepared statements with PDO driver, or you learn prepared statements with mysqli driver, but there's no "PDO prepare statements with mysqli" - that doesn't exist. You can't use PDO and mysqli at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, there is an syntax error in your MySQL query. Look at the end of your query. There is a single quotation mark missing, I think. This is your query:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `at_reg_user` where `email`='$user_id"));
```

Try with this query:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `at_reg_user` where `email`='$user_id'"));
```

Hint: untested. 
I think you should rewrite your whole code, to make it secure. It is full of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into PayPal's [Payment Data Transfer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer). It's more secure because you don't rely on $_GET data.